# How to receive C# Custom Protocol Handlers

Tags: c#, windows, client, protocols, handler

Many of us are familiar with custom protocol handlers such as ( steam://abc  or chrome://abc ). I am trying to find out from an application side how to receive them and parse the data into an open application.

So far I know it is possible to open a new copy of an existing application if I did something like this for the protocol handler:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\myapp\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\myapp\\app.exe\" \"%1\""
```

If the application is open of course I would be alright with opening a new instance and reading the argument. What I am trying to figure out is how to pass it to an open instance of a C# fat client application that is installed if the application is currently already open.

Does anyone have a reference to some code how to handle this?

Comment: I think the standard way to do this is for the new instance to check if there's an existing instance, and if there is, pass the message onto it via whatever IPC method, and then exit.

Comment: Got any code examples?

Comment: [This](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheWeeklySourceCode31SingleInstanceWinFormsAndMicrosoftVisualBasicdll.aspx) looks like a good example.